# Http response to httprequest

Tags: php, request, httprequest, httpresponse

1. I have LED device which sends continuous requests to my php page and the request is as follows:

   `xyz.com/abc/abc.php?fun=ping&deviceid=LED001&lat=8.551793&long=76.859884&dat
   e=190214&time=10:30:25`

   Now I want to send response back to led (i.e. I want to send particular response to each one who will be hitting that url i.e. to my php page)
   I want to send response as "GOOD evening"

   So how can I send a String back as a response to this request ??
2. How can I access the parameters in the above http request?
   one way I know is:

   `$_REQUEST('deviceid');`

   Is this right way to access those parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Q2, the way to get the deviceid is correct.

So to send a response back, it is just sufficient to print the values on the requested page? then just `echo "GOOD EVENING"`. In fact you don't need a device id. The device id can be used for other purposes or analytics...

Comment: no the data should be in the format -->

#OK#data=$LED001~1~128~16~128~8~2~255~0~0~0~1~1~12~1~4~1~1~1~15~4~0~2~GOOD MORNING~HAVE A NICE DAY!#

if this is the response then only led will show data !!

Comment: the response is just what you print on the page.. so edit it accordingly!!